# CSS custom text highlight that works across multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to create a custom highlight in CSS that takes up ~50% of the text height, centered vertically, that also works over multiple lines. I can do it a few ways that work on a single line, but all fall over when applied to multi line text, or aren't able to vertically center.

```css
hr {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.title-psuedo .background {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;  
}

.title-psuedo .background:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0.3em;
  height: 0.4em;
  z-index: -1;
}

.title-mark mark {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;  
}

.title-shadow .background {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.5em 0 yellow;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;  
}

.title-background .background {
  padding: 0 40px;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="title title-psuedo">
  <span class="background">This is the desired effect.</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="title title-psuedo">
  <span class="background">This works on one line, but not when the text spans onto 2 separate lines, as the background messes up and only appears on the last line of the content.</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="title title-mark">
  <mark>This works on one line, but not when the text spans onto 2 separate lines, as the lines merge into one single line which isn't legible. Also, I'm not sure the highlight can be centered vertically.</mark>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="title title-shadow">
  <span class="background">This works on multiple lines, but I'm not sure the highlight can be centered vertically. Additionally, the second line does not have the same padding as the first.</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="title title-background">
  <span class="background">This works on one line, but not when the text spans onto 2 separate lines as the line height collapses the text together and the highlight covers both lines without a gap. The second line does have the initial padding however.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: not too sure what you expect, would it be something alike : https://jsfiddle.net/whep5dmx/ ?

Comment: or like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sbunwa1k/ ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus that's almost it - I was aiming for the background to be centered vertically, but your solution keeps the padding on subsequent lines.

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's almost it too! Just the padding being missing on the subsequent lines, but I think I can combine the two.

Comment: okay, if the inline-block is not what you want, then a simple linear-gradient on an inline element will do.

Comment: then do this: https://jsfiddle.net/wg7unpko/

Comment: @TemaniAfif perfect! feel free to post that as an answer so I can accept it. I'd never heard of box-decoration-break before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gradient and `box-decoration-break`

```css
.title {
  --lineHeight: 1.4em;
}

.title span {
  line-height: var(--lineHeight);
  padding: 0 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow 0 0) 0/100% calc(var(--lineHeight)/4) no-repeat;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.title {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title title-psuedo">
  <span class="background">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget mi vitae felis molestie volutpat. Integer viverra arcu id turpis molestie, id mollis enim molestie. Proin luctus auctor dictum. Maecenas nec libero bibendum, semper erat a, tristique nunc. Fusce accumsan feugiat ante,</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with the help of `repeating-linear-gradient()` CSS property. In my solution you must define `font-size` and `line-height`. Then according to them you define the last number in `repeating-linear-gradient()`. Here is my code:

```css
.text-deco .background2 {
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent,transparent 0.9rem,yellow 0.9rem, yellow 1.1rem,transparent 1.1rem, transparent 2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="title text-deco">
     <span class="background2">This works on one line, but not when the text spans onto 2 separate lines as the line height collapses the text together and the highlight covers both lines without a gap. The second nd the highlight covers both lines without a gap. The second</span>
</div>
```

I mean that for example If you want to have `font-size:2rem` and `line-height:2` then you must change the last part (`transparent 2rem`) of `repeating-linear-gradient()` to `transparent 4rem` and then adjust other values in `repeating-linear-gradient()` according to that. For example `1.1` may change to `2.8`. Maybe now my settings does not show the **highlight** in exact vertical position, but you can adjust values to reach your desired one.